# How to use MarkerClusterer with @googlemaps/react-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

After following [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map) provided by google for adding a map and markers to a react application using @googlemaps/react-wrapper, I decided to try adding [marker clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) to my app.  However, I am unable to get the clusters to appear.

I tried following [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010596/google-maps-react-wrapper-marker-cluster-create-googlemaps-react-wrapper) but no clusters have appeared despite adding `new MarkerClusterer({ ref, markers });` to my code:

App.js

```
/*global google*/
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Wrapper } from "@googlemaps/react-wrapper";
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";
import { createCustomEqual } from "fast-equals";

const markerList = [
  { id: "A12345", uuid: "500924cf83424aad9e7d386bbec88ef6", lat: 44.459744, lng: -73.214126, assetName: "A" },
  { id: "B09423", uuid: "500924cf83424aad9e7d386bbec88ef6", lat: 44.465291, lng: -73.190723, assetName: "A" },
  { id: "C98765", uuid: "c0385833-e483-40d1-803f-2b4c26ae3799", lat: 44.476949, lng: -73.210578, assetName: "B" },
  { id: "D99999", uuid: "c0385833-e483-40d1-803f-2b4c26ae3799", lat: 44.444572, lng: -73.208741, assetName: "B" },
  { id: "E12345", uuid: "500924cf83424aad9e7d386bbec88ef6", lat: 38.459744, lng: -81.214126, assetName: "A" },
  { id: "F09423", uuid: "500924cf83424aad9e7d386bbec88ef6", lat: 38.465291, lng: -81.190723, assetName: "A" },
  { id: "G98765", uuid: "c0385833-e483-40d1-803f-2b4c26ae3799", lat: 38.476949, lng: -81.210578, assetName: "B" },
  { id: "H99999", uuid: "c0385833-e483-40d1-803f-2b4c26ae3799", lat: 38.444572, lng: -81.208741, assetName: "B" },
]

const render = (status) => {
  return <h1>{status}</h1>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(8); // initial zoom
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 44.45, lng: -73.21 });

  const onIdle = (m) => {
    console.log("onIdle");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}>
        <Wrapper
          apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}
          render={render}
        >
          <Map
            center={center}
            onIdle={onIdle}
            zoom={zoom}
            style={{ flexGrow: "1", height: "100%" }}
          />
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
    </>

  );
};

const Map = ({ onIdle, children, style, ...options }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [map, setMap] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && !map) {
      setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, {}));
    }

    // Add some markers to the map.
    const markers = markerList.map((m) => {
      return new window.google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: parseFloat(m.lat), lng: parseFloat(m.lng) }
        //map: map,
      });
    });

    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    new MarkerClusterer({ ref, markers });
  }, [ref, map]);

  useDeepCompareEffectForMaps(() => {
    if (map) {
      map.setOptions(options);
    }
  }, [map, options]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      ["click", "idle"].forEach((eventName) =>
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, eventName)
      );

      if (onIdle) {
        map.addListener("idle", () => onIdle(map));
      }
    }
  }, [map, onIdle]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} style={style} />
    </>
  );
};

const deepCompareEqualsForMaps = createCustomEqual((deepEqual) => (a, b) => {
  if (a instanceof google.maps.LatLng || b instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(a).equals(new google.maps.LatLng(b));
  }
  return deepEqual(a, b);
});

function useDeepCompareMemoize(value) {
  const ref = useRef();

  if (!deepCompareEqualsForMaps(value, ref.current)) {
    ref.current = value;
  }
  return ref.current;
}

function useDeepCompareEffectForMaps(callback, dependencies) {
  useEffect(callback, dependencies.map(useDeepCompareMemoize));
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I get MarkerClusterer to function with @googlemaps/react-wrapper?

Comment: Why did you comment the `map` assignment for markers in the code?

Comment: If I uncomment, individual markers show up on the map.  But normally when using markerclusterer you don’t use that parameter on markers, you just pass in the list of marker objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
new MarkerClusterer({ ref, markers });
```

with

```
new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });
```

PS: The answer to the mentioned question was updated